# Change password in OpenVPN configuration file

Tags: openvpn

I use OpenVPN via command line:

```
openvpn --config acme.ovpn
```

with the config file user-locked to my username.

Is there a way to change the password that protects the private key in the config file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the key is in its own file, decrypt and re-encrypt it with a new passphrase:

```
$ openssl rsa -aes256 -in acme.key -out acme.key.new
$ openssl rsa -in acme.key.new -check
$ mv acme.key.new acme.key
```

With the first command, you'll be prompted for the old passphrase once, and a new passphrase twice.  The second command isn't necessary, but is an additional sanity check that your new passphrase works with the new key file before you overwrite the original.

If your openvpn config is in the newer unified style, use your favorite editor to copy the key (including the `-----BEGIN ...` and `-----END ...` lines) from the config file into a separate file; change the passphrase as above; then copy the key back into the configuration file.

Comment: Where do you find the .key files?